# How to translate object in ARCore and Sceneform?

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I build an AR application on Android, using ARCore and Sceneform, and I want to translate object on `x`, `y` or `z` axis when user clicks a button.

How can I do that?

I try to do that, when user press the button, I'm compose object Pose with translate Pose, remove object and create new one with translation. But after some clicks, I have SIG 9 (kill app).

Is there the other way?

Answer (score 0):

> You can translate a 3D object between two anchors using a button and the [following approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337504/how-to-move-object-from-anchor-to-anchor).

or

> For translating your object along the surface you should use [OnGestureListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener) interface with its useful public methods such as:

- onDown(MotionEvent e)
- onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
- onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
- onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
- onShowPress(MotionEvent e)
- onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)

Here's an example on how you can redraw an object in `onScroll()` method:

```
android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distX, float distY) {
   if (ptrCount < 2) {
       queuedSingleTaps.offer(motionEvent);
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.